# Censor Characters between the first and last character of a string in elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-iex

I want to replace/censor the characters of a username in elixir. So in the end, it should looks like in the bidders list in ebay:
[image]

in elixir there is the String replace function, but i am a newbe at regex and i dont know what elixir-regex supports. so how can i achieve this?

```
iex> String.replace("username1234", someregex, "***")
"u***4"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you surely might accomplish this with regex “replace all but the first and the last symbols”

```elixir
String.replace "username1234", ~r/(?<=\A.).*(?=.\z)/, "***"
#⇒ "u***4"
```

I’d better go with [`String.slice/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#slice/3)

```elixir
first = String.slice("username1234", 0, 1)
last = String.slice("username1234", -1, 1)
"#{first}***#{last}"
#⇒ "u***4"
```

or [`String.graphemes/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#graphemes/1)

```elixir
[h | t] = String.graphemes("username1234")
h <> "***" <> List.last(t)
#⇒ "u***4"
```

Comment: Thanks for that. What do you think is most performant option?

Comment: I do not think about performance, I benchmark. Here it does not matter, because the impact is less than tiny, but if you are curious, `String.split/3` would be _most likely_ the most performant one.